# Merge Salesforce with Active directory

Tags: apex, contact, developer

We are currently implementing Salesforce in our development. We have a list of all current employees in our business and I was asked to upload the contacts that are in a csv file that is pulled through an FTP. I need to create a way to get a csv from the server and then upload it to Salesforce. Another issue is that this has to be done 4 times a day automatically and obviously without repeating the contacts into the salesforce databse. I am aware that this isn't an "I did this" and its wrong question, but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to achieve single sign on (SSO) or simply sync Salesforce contacts with your Active directory?

There are 3rd party tools available like this one for a bi-directional sync between AD and SF.
http://www.onelogin.com/active-directory-connector/

You can manually load contacts into SF by using a csv file and the Apex Data Loader. You will need to format your .csv file per the data loader requirements.

But if you need to update the contacts multiple times a day, it better to create an integration. If you are a developer you can user C# or Java to write an application that will update SF contacts with AD data. You can make a check to see if the record exists to determine if you need to insert or update it.